# How to use \perform of lhs2tex in a \newcommand

Tags: macros, lhs2tex

I was trying to define a command `\runx`, which not only evaluates a Haskell expression (this is what `\perform` already does), but also prints the expression before the evaluation.

So I tried

```
\newcommand{\runx}[1]{result=\ttfamily{#1} \perform{#1} }
```

and use it like

```
\runx{pi}
```

It turns out the expression sent to ghci is a literal `#1` and not `pi`. So `\perform` is obviously applied too early for my purpose, namely at the time when the command is defined. Ghci returns nothing useful when asked to evaluate `#1` and `\perform{#1}` evaluates to nothing.

- Thus  `\runx{pi}` becomes
- `{result=\ttfamily{pi} \perform{#1} }` which becomes
- `{result=\ttfamily{pi}}`

Thus the result of evaluating `pi` is lost in my pdf document, and I only see:

[image]

Is there a way to make `\perform` less eager?

Comment: the content of a `\newcommand` is not executed at all at the point of definition `\perform` need not even be defined. I assume `\perform` is a verbatim-like command so can not be used as you use it here in the definiton of another command, but that wouldn't affect an argument like `pi` only if the argument had special characters that need to be read verbatim

Comment: oh unless you are using a preprocessor that replaces `\perform` by the results ghc evaluation before the tex is run, rather than tex executing external commands as encountered?

Comment: This is most likely the case.  I believe \perform is not really a TEX thing, but an instruction to the lhs2tex preprocessor. Unfortunately it looks like a TEX thing for some reason. So this question is really specific to lhs2tex.